# Files in Media and Plupload module not showing in content selector

Tags: 7, media

I've got the Media module installed along with Plupload. I go to the Media listing, click Add File, then I drop 3 files onto the Drag and Drop area. They show up correctly and I click Upload. They all upload correctly and the Media listing reloads and they all show up.

However, when I go to add Content and click Select Media to choose those files they are not listed.

If I go to the Media List, click Add File and then I use the File Selector to select those same 3 files and upload them that way... it works properly and I can choose them in the Content Select Media popup.

I've verified this on Chrome and Firefox. Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone run into this before? I'll post this as an issue on the Media module, but I figured maybe someone here had experienced this.

Comment: What version of the Media Module are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest 2.x-dev versions of media and file_entity modules.  I doubt you will see this issue anymore.